# Calling same function on multiple thread increases performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, multiple-columns

In my Application i have structure some thing like below

```
if(iterationCount==-3)
{

  CreatFullNetwork(obj1)
}

if(iterationCount==-2)
{
  CreatFullNetwork(obj2)//Method is same as previous
}

if(iterationCount==-1)
{
//Obj1,2,3 are same object but the sorting order variables inside object are different
  CreatFullNetwork(obj3)//Method is same as previous
}
```

To increase performance i am planning to create 3 threads and run it parallel.Is this a good approach will it work.
Note: `CreatFullNetwork()` is very huge method it has sub methods in it and creates lots of collections and updates them

Comment: Does it matter whether the function calls are made in order or not? Is the code CPU bound?

Comment: Your question doesn't makes sense. Why checking different conditions and call same method? Why not just call without any condition

Comment: No it does not matter however the functions are called.

Comment: If the method is very large, runs long and only accesses local resources (no instance or global variables) it will run faster. However, if they access shared variables you easily can get racing conditions and you always have to lock the resource first (which decreases performance again).

Comment: @SriramSakthivel my edit may answer your question

Comment: @user2674389 Yes this method uses a lot of shared variables so you mean to say i need to use lock conditions and because of which performance decreases ?

Comment: Is this code CPU bound. When you run it does your program run a 100% CPU utilization on the processor that executes the code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no it wont uses 100% CPU utilization

Comment: @Shrivallabh You want to lock critical parts of your code that needs to be executed by one thread at a time. For example, shared buffers.

Comment: In which case it's probably pointless to multi-thread. That only helps CPU bound code.

Comment: @Shrivallabh It can happen that two threads access a variable at the same time, while one overwrites the change of the other - but both threads will work with the newer value. This can result in unexpected and unwanted results. One way to avoid this is to lock these variables as long as needed - but as long as they're locked, every other thread that tries to lock this variable too will be blocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment you state that the function call is not CPU bound. It does not reach close to 100% CPU utilization. In which case it seems very unlikely that your program's performance is liable to be improved by multi-threading.

On top of that it seems that your code uses a lot of shared variables that are not synchronized. Before you could even contemplate running the code in parallel you'd need to deal with that issue. Typically there are two ways to do that:

1. Serialize access to shared variables to avoid data races.
2. Arrange for each thread a private copy of the information and variables it needs.

Generally speaking, option 2 is better since serialization has performance overhead due to the use of locks. However, option 2 may be hard to achieve and can have its own performance issues in case you need to copy a lot of data.

Most of this is moot if your code is not CPU bound. That said, perhaps the bottleneck is at a different machine. Perhaps the bottleneck is in database access. If the database can handle parallel access efficiently then perhaps threading will help.

The bottom line is that you need to have a much clearer understanding of what your code is doing and what is limiting performance before you can contemplate options to speed it up. Threading is not a universal panacea. It won't help speed up all programs, and you always need to know how best to deploy it.